# Xcode preview doesn't work with generic view

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I want to use generic subview in SwiftUI view.

```
struct UserChoiceView<DecisionView: View>: View {
    let subview: DecisionView
    var body: some View {
        subview
            .padding()
            .offset(x: 10)
    }
}

struct LikeDislikeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UserChoiceView(subview: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                                    .fill(Color.red.opacity(0.9)))
    }
}
```

Code above works fine, but Xcode can't generate preview.
I receive this error:

```
reference to generic type 'UserChoiceView' requires arguments in <...>
```

I think I can solve this by using AnyView type erasure, but maybe there are other workarounds.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine and shows preview without any issues. Try clearing the derived data, clean project and build to see if it works.

Comment: Did you found a way to resolve this issue? I have the same problem and cannot figure out how to get it working. If not, I'll report the issue to Apple.

Comment: Also looking for an answer to this

Comment: In my case, I had nested generic views (a parent generic view has a child generic view) so I put a child generic view out of a parent child generic view then preview error was fixed

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly define the view in the preview.

```
struct UserChoiceView<DecisionView: View>: View {
    let subview: DecisionView

    var body: some View {
        /// ...
    }
}

struct LikeDislikeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var decisionView: View {
        // return SomeDecisionView()
    }

    static var previews: some View {
        UserChoiceView<Self.decisionView>(subview: Self.decisionView)
    }
}
```